# Is LGPL compatible with GPLv3?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, gpl-3, lgpl

If I have a project using LGPL ([GNU Lesser General Public License](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.html)), would I be able to use within it another component which is under GPLv3?

Is there any site where I can see all the compatible licenses with GPLv3?

Answer (score 5):

Yes; both LGPLv2.1 and LGPLv3 are compatible with GPLv3.  You can find more details, and the resource you were looking for, at the FSF's [licence summary page](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html), which includes their take on which licences are compatible with the various versions of the GNU GPL.

Comment: Perhaps it's also worth mentioning the [(L)GPL compatibility matrix](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#AllCompatibility) which is much less comprehensive but covers GPL-LGPL interaction more closely.